# Simple interpreter written in Rust

Tags: rust, interpreter

I'd like to improve how ownership is handled within a simple interpreter written in Rust.  The interpreter takes simple calculator like expressions and returns either a string of the AST or a number of the evaluation:

```
// Simple expression for working on numbers
enum Exp {
    Add { e1 : Box <Exp>, e2 : Box <Exp> },
    Mul { e1 : Box <Exp>, e2 : Box <Exp> },
    Int { i : i32}
}

// Evaluate an expression to a number
fn exp_to_num(e : Exp) -> i32 {
    match e {
        Exp::Add {e1,e2} => return exp_to_num(*e1) + exp_to_num(*e2),
        Exp::Mul {e1,e2} => return exp_to_num(*e1) * exp_to_num(*e2),
        Exp::Int {i} => return i
    }
}

// Evaluate an expression to a string
fn exp_to_str(e : Exp) -> String {
    match e {
        Exp::Add {e1,e2} =>
            return format!("({}) + ({})",exp_to_str(*e1),exp_to_str(*e2)),
        Exp::Mul {e1,e2} =>
            return format!("({}) * ({})",exp_to_str(*e1),exp_to_str(*e2)),
        Exp::Int {i} =>
            return format!("{}",i)
    }
}

fn main() {

    // Create an expression
    let e1 = Exp::Add {
        e1 : Box::new(Exp::Mul {
            e1 : Box::new(Exp::Int { i : 2 }),
            e2 : Box::new(Exp::Int { i : 3 })}),
        e2 : Box::new(Exp::Int {i : 4})};

    // Evaluate the expression
    println!("e1 : {}", exp_to_num(e1));
    //println!("e1 : {}", exp_to_str(e1));
}
```

The last command can not be uncommented since it appears as though `exp_to_num` takes ownership of `e1`.  I'd like to fix this.

In C++, I'd just make the arguments `const &`.  In Rust, my best attempt at this is the following code:

```
// Simple expression for working on numbers
enum Exp {
    Add { e1 : Box <Exp>, e2 : Box <Exp> },
    Mul { e1 : Box <Exp>, e2 : Box <Exp> },
    Int { i : i32}
}

// Evaluate an expression to a number
fn exp_to_num(e : & Exp) -> i32 {
    match *e {
        Exp::Add {ref e1,ref e2} => return exp_to_num(&*e1) + exp_to_num(&*e2),
        Exp::Mul {ref e1,ref e2} => return exp_to_num(&*e1) * exp_to_num(&*e2),
        Exp::Int {i} => return i
    }
}

// Evaluate an expression to a string
fn exp_to_str(e : & Exp) -> String {
    match *e {
        Exp::Add {ref e1,ref e2} =>
            return format!("({}) + ({})",exp_to_str(&*e1),exp_to_str(&*e2)),
        Exp::Mul {ref e1,ref e2} =>
            return format!("({}) * ({})",exp_to_str(&*e1),exp_to_str(&*e2)),
        Exp::Int {i} =>
            return format!("{}",i)
    }
}

fn main() {

    // Create an expression
    let e1 = Exp::Add {
        e1 : Box::new(Exp::Mul {
            e1 : Box::new(Exp::Int { i : 2 }),
            e2 : Box::new(Exp::Int { i : 3 })}),
        e2 : Box::new(Exp::Int {i : 4})};

    // Evaluate the expression
    println!("e1 : {}", exp_to_num(&e1));
    println!("e1 : {}", exp_to_str(&e1));
}
```

Though this works, it feels verbose.  Specifically, it feels verbose to match references, `Exp::Add {ref e1,ref e2}`, and verbose to find a reference to an unboxed expression, `exp_to_num(&*e1)`.  Can passing a constant reference be made more concise and compact?

Alternatively, we could just clone the memory, which gives

```
// Simple expression for working on numbers
#[derive(Clone)]
enum Exp {
    Add { e1 : Box <Exp>, e2 : Box <Exp> },
    Mul { e1 : Box <Exp>, e2 : Box <Exp> },
    Int { i : i32}
}

// Evaluate an expression to a number
fn exp_to_num(e : Exp) -> i32 {
    match e {
        Exp::Add {e1,e2} => return exp_to_num(*e1) + exp_to_num(*e2),
        Exp::Mul {e1,e2} => return exp_to_num(*e1) * exp_to_num(*e2),
        Exp::Int {i} => return i
    }
}

// Evaluate an expression to a string
fn exp_to_str(e : Exp) -> String {
    match e {
        Exp::Add {e1,e2} =>
            return format!("({}) + ({})",exp_to_str(*e1),exp_to_str(*e2)),
        Exp::Mul {e1,e2} =>
            return format!("({}) * ({})",exp_to_str(*e1),exp_to_str(*e2)),
        Exp::Int {i} =>
            return format!("{}",i)
    }
}

fn main() {

    // Create an expression
    let e1 = Exp::Add {
        e1 : Box::new(Exp::Mul {
            e1 : Box::new(Exp::Int { i : 2 }),
            e2 : Box::new(Exp::Int { i : 3 })}),
        e2 : Box::new(Exp::Int {i : 4})};

    // Evaluate the expression
    println!("e1 : {}", exp_to_num(e1.clone()));
    println!("e1 : {}", exp_to_str(e1.clone()));
}
```

This also feels somewhat verbose because we have to call clone rather than just allowing an implicit copy.  Is a clone required due to `Box`?  Can this be made more concise?

Answer (score 6):

1. Learn to love [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). It will correct your code to the idiomatic Rust style.
2. Learn to love [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy). It will provide more lints to change your code to be more idiomatic. For example, it identifies many unneeded `return` statements in your code.
3. When you accept a reference, you do not need to dereference and reference it. You can just use the variable directly.
4. Recent Rust versions removed the need to use `ref` in patterns when it's "obviously" the right thing. It also removed the need to match on a dereferenced variable (`match *foo`).
5. Instead of calling `format!("{}", foo)`, just call `foo.to_string()`.
6. Instead of having functions called `foo_bar` taking a `Foo` as the first argument, make them methods. Methods can automatically take references to their `self` parameter.
7. Naming the subexpressions and integer value doesn't really bring much value. I'd switch to a tuple struct.
8. Bringing the variants of the enum into scope in a method (`use Foo::*`) can reduce duplication.
9. Instead of creating a custom `to_str` method, implement `Display`.
10. Use `///` for documentation comments.

```
use std::fmt;

/// Simple expression for working on numbers
enum Exp {
    Add(Box<Exp>, Box<Exp>),
    Mul(Box<Exp>, Box<Exp>),
    Int(i32),
}

impl Exp {
    /// Evaluate an expression to a number
    fn to_num(&self) -> i32 {
        use Exp::*;
        match self {
            Add(e1, e2) => e1.to_num() + e2.to_num(),
            Mul(e1, e2) => e1.to_num() * e2.to_num(),
            Int(i) => *i,
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Exp {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use Exp::*;
        match self {
            Add(e1, e2) => write!(f, "({}) + ({})", e1, e2),
            Mul(e1, e2) => write!(f, "({}) * ({})", e1, e2),
            Int(i) => write!(f, "{}", i),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Create an expression
    let e1 = Exp::Add(
        Box::new(Exp::Mul(Box::new(Exp::Int(2)), Box::new(Exp::Int(3)))),
        Box::new(Exp::Int(4)),
    );

    // Evaluate the expression
    println!("e1 : {}", e1.to_num());
    println!("e1 : {}", e1);
}
```